# R join table based on ID and Date, complex rolling join?

Tags: r, join, data.table

I have to join two data tables to get the part_ID of a part that I need to predict whether or not the part will fail (part_ID is not in the test data). I am struggling joining the tables correctly.

The machine has 4 pieces that are active, part_A, part_B, Part_C, part_D. I currently have the date each was installed (Dates table) and measurements taken each second that correspond to the part with a timestamp by second (SensorData). I can do a rolling join on the machine_ID and the date to add the Part_ID but if part_ID 0 was installed on 1/1/2016 and part_B was installed on 2/2/2016 it doesn't mean part_A was removed (although it could have been), only that another piece was added and something was removed (not part of the problem I am trying to solve). How can I join the two tables to keep the data for part_B and also part_B as depicted below.

```
SensorData
ID  timestamp           v1   v2  v3  ... v28  Machine_ID
1   1/1/2016 12:00:13  .001 .123 1.3 ... 24.6 23
2   1/1/2016 12:00:14  .002 .122 1.2 ... 24.9 14
3   1/1/2016 12:00:15  .005 .025 NA  ... 23.1 6
4   1/2/2016 12:00:15  .005 .025 NA  ... 23.1 6

Dates
InstallDate Part_ID Machine_ID
1/1/2016    0        23
1/1/2016    2        14
1/1/2016    16        6
1/2/2016    24        6

Results 
ID  timestamp           v1   v2  v3  ... v28  Machine_ID Part_A  Part_B
1   1/1/2016 12:00:13  .001 .123 1.3 ... 24.6 23         0       NA
2   1/1/2016 12:00:14  .002 .122 1.2 ... 24.9 14         2       NA
3   1/1/2016 12:00:15  .005 .025 NA  ... 23.1 6          16      NA
4   1/2/2016 12:00:15  .005 .025 NA  ... 23.1 6          16      24
```

A data.table solution would be prefered, but I am open to any solution. The data has been shredded and condensed to this point so its about 100,000 rows, so any solution would work regardless of speed.

This currently partially works:

```
setkey(Dates, Machine_ID, InstallDate)
setkey(SensorData, Machine_ID, timestamp)
dx<-SensorData[Dates, roll=T]
```

But this assumes Part_A was removed and Part_B was installed and yields a table like this:

```
IncorrectResults 
ID  timestamp           v1   v2  v3  ... v28  Machine_ID Part_A  
1   1/1/2016 12:00:13  .001 .123 1.3 ... 24.6 23         0       
2   1/1/2016 12:00:14  .002 .122 1.2 ... 24.9 14         2       
3   1/1/2016 12:00:15  .005 .025 NA  ... 23.1 6          16      
4   1/2/2016 12:00:15  .005 .025 NA  ... 23.1 6          24
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to assume your dates and timestamps are in `POSIXct` format. I'm also guessing a little as to what you want, but this should be easy to modify to suit your exact needs if I guessed incorrectly.

```
# add a part number column
Dates[, Part_Num := paste0("Part_", LETTERS[1:.N]), by = Machine_ID]

# do a non-equi join, and dcast the result
dcast(Dates[SensorData, on = .(Machine_ID, InstallDate <= timestamp)],
      ... ~ Part_Num, value.var = 'Part_ID')
#           InstallDate Machine_ID ID    v1    v2  v3  v28 Part_A Part_B
#1: 2016-01-01 12:00:13         23  1 0.001 0.123 1.3 24.6      0     NA
#2: 2016-01-01 12:00:14         14  2 0.002 0.122 1.2 24.9      2     NA
#3: 2016-01-01 12:00:15          6  3 0.005 0.025  NA 23.1     16     NA
#4: 2016-01-02 12:00:15          6  4 0.005 0.025  NA 23.1     16     24
```

You will need the [latest devel version](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation) (1.9.7+) of `data.table` to run the above.

Comment: The solution looks like the right path but I am getting the following error.

Comment: 'Error in vecseq(f__, len__, if (allow.cartesian || notjoin || !anyDuplicated(f__,  : 
  Join results in 2981318 rows; more than 428002 = nrow(x)+nrow(i). Check for duplicate key values in i each of which join to the same group in x over and over again. If that's ok, try by=.EACHI to run j for each group to avoid the large allocation. If you are sure you wish to proceed, rerun with allow.cartesian=TRUE. Otherwise, please search for this error message in the FAQ, Wiki, Stack Overflow and datatable-help for advice.'